# Как получать значение value скрытого инпута?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    var handle = $("#custom-handle2");
    $("#slider2").slider({
        range: "min",
        create: function () {
            handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            handle.text(ui.value);
                   
            $("#resultValue2").val(ui.value);  
            
        }
    });

let total; 
 $('#resultValue2').on('change', function () {
        
            let num = Number($(this).val());
            if (num == 0) {
                num = 1;
            }
            total = num;

    });

$(".total").text( total + ' ₽/мес');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

     <div class="calc-slider">
                    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="users"  id="resultValue2">
                    <div id="slider2">

                        <div id="custom-handle2" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<span class="total">Итого: </span>
```

В форме используется jq ui slider который передаёт значение в скрытый инпут. Как получать это значение при изменении?
Пробовал через

```
.on('input')
```

не передаёт так.

Comment: Тоже пробовал, не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

*Просто убрал лишнее из вашего кода, прописав всё, что должно произойти, в slide:function

```js
var handle = $("#custom-handle2");
   $("#slider2").slider({
        range: "min",
        create: function () {
            handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
        },
        slide: function (event,ui) {
          let total = ui.value;
          handle.text(total);          
          $('.total').text( total + ' ₽/мес' );
        }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="calc-slider">
    <div id="slider2">
       <div id="custom-handle2" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
    </div>
</div>

Итого: <span class="total">0 ₽/мес</span>
```

Comment: Добавил код к сообщению. Дело в том, что инпут скрыт, да. И в него данные с клавиатуры не вводятся.

Comment: Немного поигрался, вроде работает. Если в будущем этот инпут нужно было где-то еще использовать, можно попросту объявить let total; в самом верху, вне функции. и использовать значение total вместо $(input).val();

Answer (score 0):

Изменение значения инпута в коде не вызывает события `change`.

```
$("#resultValue2").val(ui.value).change();
```

```js
var handle = $("#custom-handle2");
$("#slider2").slider({
  range: "min",
  create: function() {
    handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
  },
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    handle.text(ui.value);
    $("#resultValue2").val(ui.value).change();
  }
});

let total;
$('#resultValue2').on('change', function() {
  let num = Number($(this).val());
  if (num == 0) {
    num = 1;
  }
  total = num;
  $(".total").text(total + ' ₽/мес');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="calc-slider">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="users" id="resultValue2">
  <div id="slider2">

    <div id="custom-handle2" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<span class="total">Итого: </span>
```